# Reading from stdout pipe once ready in golang

Tags: go, stdout, stdin

I'm facing with a weird golang issue. The following code will clarify:

```
package main

import (
    "os/exec"
    "io"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

var (
    pw io.WriteCloser
    pr io.ReadCloser
)

func main() {
    term := exec.Command("/bin/sh")

    // Get stdin writer pipe
    pw, _ = term.StdinPipe()
    pr, _ = term.StdoutPipe()

    term.Start()

    run("cd ~")
    pwd := run("pwd");

    // Do something with pwd output
    ...

    term.Wait()
}

func run(c string) string {
    io.WriteString(pw, fmt.Sprintln(c))

    buf := make([]byte, 32 * 1024)
    pr.Read(buf)
    return string(buf)
}
```

I'd like to run some commands in a shell env and read their output. There's no problem on write/run command but it seems that there're some limitations while reading:

- you can't know if a command doesn't output anything or not;
- there's no way to check if stdout is ready to be read or not.

The `pr.Read(dest)` method will block the code flow until something is read from stdout. As said, the goal is to read sequentially (without using a go routine and/or an infinite loop). This means that if we send a `cd` command the func end is never reached.

Setting the non-block flag through `unix.SetNonblock` on stdout file descriptor seems to solve the above issue but you can't know prior if it's ready or not and an error saying "resource temporary not available" is returned from `.Read` call.

Comment: Why don't you just run the command you really want to run, instead of trying to start a shell?

Comment: What is the reason for not using a goroutine?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Unfortunately once you kill the process (shell) you can't retrieve the current working path and the shell is restarted with binary path as working path.

Comment: @CeriseLimón in that case, a goroutine, will be the worst solution imho. I need to read output from different functions sequentially.

Comment: What are the functions you are talking about?  The example shows one function, `main`.   In any case, the use of goroutines does not prevent sequential read of the sub process stdout.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I've updated the code. As you can see the first command (cd ~) does not produce any output and the code will hang once `pr.Read(buf)` is reached since there's nothing to be read.

Setting a non-block flag will solve this issue but when the second one (pwd) is written, the stdout is not yet ready to be read so I got a "resource temporary not available" error.

Comment: The non-blocking flag does not help determine when the grandchild process is done writing output. It's no better than just reading the connection.  What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?  If your goal is to find the home directory as shown in the question, then use the [os/user](https://godoc.org/os/user#User.HomeDir) package.

Comment: The whole approach doesn't make any sense. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

As Cerise Limón mentioned go functions whould be the way to go here, since these sorts of interactive scripting exercises are traditionally done with expect.

You can wrap the the parrellel execution into a library to it might still look like sequencial code, so this might be helpful: https://github.com/ThomasRooney/gexpect

From the readme:

```
child, err := gexpect.Spawn("python")
if err != nil { panic(err) }
child.Expect(">>>")
child.SendLine("print 'Hello World'")
child.Interact()
child.Close()
```